# How to write linq function query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-extensions

```
IRun<string, bool> runstub = c => One(1) == true;
exec(runstub);
```

What's wrong here? It gives an exception "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IRun' because it is not a delegate type"

```
public static IEnumerable<IStub> exec<T, M>(T t) where T : IRun<T, M>
{
}

public static bool One(int one)
{
    one.Dump();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it; where is M defined? (For reference, T is defined just after `exec<`)

Comment: Do you mean Func<string, bool> instead of IRun<string, bool> ? I didn't understand your question.

Comment: No, that is interface for Func. Like this one: public interface IStub
{
 object exe<T>(Func<T> func);
}